# Motherboard prints no POST messages at all, but otherwise works perfectly -- is this normal?

Tags: motherboard, post

I bought a slot A3+ motherboard ([Gigabyte ATX GA990ZA-UD3-R5](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5294#ov)) with an AMD FX-8320E CPU. It works fine, all eight cores are enabled, dual-channel memory works, as well as everything I could test (audio, SATA, lan...) I'm actually posting this question from this new machine.

But when I turn it on, it prints no POST messages at all. It displays a splash screen offering me to press a key to enter setup. But after that, the screen stays blank until the bootloader starts writing. Is this expexted, or is the motherboard defective?

I think it *is* doing POST, but not writing POST messages to the screen. BIOS seems to have no option related to that.

Comment: Honestly I've never seen a motherboard/BIOS show a POST message when there aren't any issues, although I've really only dealt with Dell and Asus boards/machines. As for the memory issue, it's best not to re-ask it since you already have a post for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's normal.  Unless there's an issue with the motherboard or some other component on it, most users don't care about all of the plain old boring text.  So motherboard manufacturers started hiding it all with the splash screen that you pointed out.  This also helps to market the board to people who want everything to be as flashy/gaudy as possible.  There should be a way to disable the splash screen on start up from your BIOS's settings.  I have a Gigabyte MB as well and the option you're probably going to want to change is: "Full Screen LOGO show".  Could be a bit off as this motherboard is 3 years old and they could have changed it by now.

Comment: Oh, well... It seems that it's been a *really* long time since I bought my previous motherboard... Things have changed! :-) Thank you!